# Source dependent files

Tags: r

How can one source files that are dependent upon each other in the way packages load functions and they all work.  Here's a MWE:

```
dir.create("temp")
cat("bar <- foo + 1", file="temp/bar.R")
cat("foo <- 3", file="temp/foo.R")

lapply(file.path("temp", list.files("temp")), source)
```

This results in:

```
## > lapply(file.path("temp", list.files("temp")), source)
## Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'foo' not found
```

This makes sense because `bar` needs `foo` but foo hasn't loaded yet.  Is there a way to load them (not knowing the dependencies order a head of time) and they will be available in some environment and work as defined?

Answer (score 0):

A possibility but it seems like there's a better way:

```
fls <- file.path("temp", dir("temp"))
m <- rep(TRUE, length(fls))
env <- new.env(parent = globalenv())

while (sum(m) > 0) {
    output <- lapply(fls, function(x){
        try(sys.source(x, envir = env, keep.source = FALSE), TRUE)
    })
    m[sapply(output, is.null)] <- FALSE
}

ls(env)
```